Suddenly uploading file to Express not working on Cpanel but working fine on local
So, i have a project where it can upload csv file and import it to DB, at first the application working fine on local and on cPanel, but a few days ago the upload endpoint does not work at all at cPanel. The rest of the endpoints works well, only the upload function that fail.
I already test using immediate response like this
// ./controller/customer-service.js

const addCustomerByImport = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).json("success")
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
}

But it doesn't even work at all. The endpoint only work when i upload smaller csv file (few KiloBytes) but when i upload 2mb csv it will not work at all.
I already search for what might be causing the issue but i didn't find the solution. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to make file uploads work properly on cPanel?
Note: The SWAP Memory usage on cPanel is at 100% does it impact the endpoint?

If your SWAP memory usage is at 100%, this could definitely impact the performance of your application. High memory usage can cause slowdowns or timeouts, especially when handling larger files. Consider optimizing your application or checking if you can increase your memory limit.
